# On sequence of absolutely continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was working on some past qual problems and was having difficulty with a question relating to a sequence of absolutely continuous random variables.

Loosely speaking, a random variable $X$ is absolutely continuous if there exists a function $\varphi$ such the $P(X\in A) = \int_A\varphi(x)dx$ for all Borel set $A$.

Can someone please show me how to construct  a sequence of absolutely continuous random variables $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ whose density functions $f_n$ satisfy $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ a.s., but for which $X_n$ converges to the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $0 < a_n < \frac{1}{2^n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n a_n < \infty$. Then for each $n\geq 1$, let $X_n$ be a random variable having the p.d.f. $f_{X_n}$ of the form

$$ f_{X_n}(x) = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} \frac{1}{a_n} \mathbf{1}_{[k/2^n, k/2^n+a_n]}(x) $$

**1.** Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \operatorname{Leb}(\{x : f_{X_n}(x) \neq 0 \}) < \infty $, the Borel–Cantelli lemma tells that $f_{X_n}(x) = 0$ for all but finitely many $n$'s for Lebesgue-a.e. $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This proves that $f_{X_n} \to 0$ a.e.

**2.** Moreover, for each $m \geq 1$ and $0 \leq k \leq 2^m$, the following holds:

$$ F_{X_n}(k/2^m) = \int_{0}^{k/2^m} f_{X_n}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = k/2^m \quad\text{whenever}\quad n \geq m. $$

In particular, $F_{X_n}(x) \to F_{\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)}(x)$ at each dyadic rational $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and hence $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converges in distribution to a random variable having the uniform distribution over $[0,1]$.